# If $A$ is a deformation retract of $V$ then $H_n(X,A) \simeq H_n(X,V)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

I'd like to prove that if $A$ is a retraction of deformation of $V$, where $A \subset V \subset X$, then $H_n(X,V) \simeq H_n(X,A)$ using the five lemma. I thought I could reach the diagram from the exact sequence of pair of $(X,V)$ and $(X,A)$ in the following way. Consider

$$ \cdots \longrightarrow H_n(V) \longrightarrow H_n(X) \longrightarrow H_n(X,V) \longrightarrow H_{n-1}(V) \longrightarrow H_{n-1}(X) \longrightarrow \cdots$$

$$ \cdots \longrightarrow H_n(A) \longrightarrow H_n(X) \longrightarrow H_n(X,A) \longrightarrow H_{n-1}(A) \longrightarrow H_{n-1}(X) \longrightarrow \cdots$$

As far as concerns the vertical arrow I could use the isomorphism $i_* : H_n(A) \longrightarrow H_n(V)$ induced by the homotopic equivalence $i$. I'd like to conclude that $H_n(X,A) \simeq H_n(X,V)$ completing the diagram with the map induced by the identity of $X$, $id_* : H_n(X) \longrightarrow H_n(X)$ but I don't wheter the diagram commutes to correctly appy the five lemma, to exploit the naturality of the connection homomorphism $\partial : H_n(X,A) \longrightarrow H_{n-1}(A)$, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the map of pairs $\phi : (X,A) \to (X,V), \phi(x) = x$. Its "absolute" part is the identity $id_X : X \to X$ and its "relative" part the inclusion $\phi_A : A \to V$ which is a homotopy equivalence in this case. Hence we get induced maps $(id_X)_* = id : H_n(X) \to H_n(X)$, $(\phi_A)_* : H_n(A) \to H_n(V)$ and $\phi_* : H_n(X,A) \to H_n(X,V)$, where $(\phi_A)_*$ is an isomorphism. These maps connect the two long exact sequences in your question. Each of the resulting squares commutes because the $H_n$ are functors and $\partial$ is natural for maps of pairs.

Now the five lemma applies.

Comment: This is what I had in mind without knowing how to complete the diagram, how are the absolute and relative part of a map defined ? Or what do you intend for it ? Thanks

Comment: The homology functors are defined on the category $Top^2$ of pairs $(X,A)$ of spaces and maps of pairs $f : (X,A) \to (Y,B)$. A map of pairs is a map $f : X \to Y$ (which I called the absolute part) such that $f(A) \subset B$. I called the restriction $f_A  : A  \to B$ of $f$ the relative part. For each pair $(X,A)$ we get two maps of pairs $i : (A,\emptyset) \to (X,\emptyset)$ and $j : (X,\emptyset) \to (X,A)$ which induce morphisms $i_* : H_n(A) = H_n(A,\emptyset) \to H_n(X,\emptyset) = H_n(X)$ and  $j_* : H_n(X)  = H_n(X,\emptyset) \to H_n(X,A)$.

Comment: Moreover, $\partial : H_n(X,A) \to H_n(A,\emptyset) = H_n(A)$ is natural for maps of a pairs. This means that $f : (X,A) \to (Y,B)$ induces a sequence of maps connecting the long exact sequences of the pairs $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$. All resulting squares commute by functoriality of the $H_n$ are the naturality of $ \partial$.